# Imports cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, gwt

These imports cannot be resolved in my app, I'm using GWT 2.5.1, and I checked the maven lib in the project and gwt is there:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JField;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JMethod;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JParameter;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JPrimitiveType;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JType;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.TypeOracle;
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you please add the pom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `{gwt.version}` with your version like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version> //<== this here you should add
</dependency>
```

I think this will solve the dependencies.

I guess the dependency you found showed a general template but you should adjust it to your version. I see that you may use different `<artifactId>` (e.g. `<artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>`) but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the needed jar files like  `gwt-dev-modified.jar`  to your class path?