# Import cannot be resolved after converting project to faceted form

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a project with multiple modules. I am using Maven , Eclipse, and jdk 1.8. 
However a couple of modules were not being recognized as java projects such that class search was not working and F3 too was not working. 
I converted the project into faceted form. Now, it is showing Java nature but several imports cannot be resolved now.
The following is not working for me [Convert Eclipse project type from general to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592081/convert-eclipse-project-type-from-general-to-java) , [Imports cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278468/imports-cannot-be-resolved) .

Comment: Are you missing some third party libs, or core JDK classes?

Comment: Which imports? Where do they come from?

Answer (score 0):

After changing to JAVA you must have to check the build path and should resolved the issues.

Right click on each module and go to build path->configure build path.

You can find the missing libraries and build related issues. resolve it first.